# How to submit each form from many form

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to build a friend request system. I have registered users, which echo with an add button and each user has a form that is automatically created when a user creates an account. My problem is how do I submit each form? With what I have now when this users add button is submitted it will submit only the form of the first user in the database even when the add button is for the 4 or 5 user.

index.php

```
<div class="users_b">
     <?php
     include 'db.php';

        $sq = "select * from alert_users_account";
        $query = mysqli_query($con,$sq);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

     ?>
     <div class="user_dis_p" id="user<?php echo $row['id']?>">
     <div id="user_img"><a href="alert_profile.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>"><img src="alert<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>">
     </a></div> <div id="user_fs">
     <a href="alert_profile.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">
     <?php  echo $row['firstname']." "." "." "." ".$row['surname'];?></a><form id="upload_file_f">
     <input type="text" name="friend_id" id="friend_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" readonly>
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
$("#upload_file_f").on("submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url:"request.php",
   data:new FormData(this),
   contentType:false,
   processData:false,
   cache:false,
   success: function(data){
   $("#msg").html(data);
   }

});

});

});
</script>
```

Comment: `each user has a form that is automatically create when user creates account`  I see only one form `<form id="upload_file_f" ...`  and `it will submit only the form of the first user in the database` .  Most likely you need to use a class for these instead of a ID, Id's are posta be unique.

Comment: yes i just pasted that because  all the form has same id,but when i try to give then different id with php i don't know how to call that id because users will still have to register

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I highly recommend reading [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and more specifically the "Spelling, grammar and formatting" section. I've corrected this post, and fixed some of the common mistakes, but on future posts reading this article would go a long way to making high quality posts for future visitors.

Comment: this part `i don't know how to call that id` what do you mean in javascript? as in the `on` event.

Comment: this is what the form look like

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
<form id="upload_file_f"  ...

<form id="upload_file_f"  .... '
```

and

```
$("#upload_file_f").on("submit", ....
```

Well, you cant expect the forms to work because the ID's are supposed to be unique.  Instead of re-using the Id, you must have a truly unique form id, or use a class or such as your jquery selector.

```
 $("form").on( "submit", ....

   //// $(this) within the on callback refers to the match of the selector that was clicked.
```

if you look  in your form callback there is no dependency there to the ID.

```
 <form class="myfrom" ....
```

And

```
$(".myform").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url:"request.php",
       data:new FormData(this),
       contentType:false,
       processData:false,
       cache:false,
       success: function(data){
        $("#msg").html(data);
       }

    });
});
```

Should work fine.  The only part that comes close to a dependency is this

```
$("#msg").html(data);
```

And likewise this could be a class ( `.msg` ) for example then you just do something like this

```
$(".myform").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var that = $(this); //ajax scope placeholder

    $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url:"request.php",
       data:new FormData(this),
       contentType:false,
       processData:false,
       cache:false,
       success: function(data){
            that.find(".msg").html(data);
       }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your forms all have the same ID:

Use `<form class="upload_file_f">`

And then below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
$(".upload_file_f").on("submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url:"request.php",
   data:new FormData(this),
   contentType:false,
   processData:false,
   cache:false,
   success: function(data){
   $("#msg").html(data);
   }

});

});

});
</script>
```

An easier solution though, would be to just create a function and call it with the button:

```
<button onclick="add_friend(<?php echo $friend_id; ?>)" />
```

And the javascript:

```
<script>
function add_friend(friend_id) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url:"request.php",
        data: {
            id: friend_id
        },
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        cache:false,
        success: function(data){
            $("#msg").html(data);
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: so in this line  function add_friend(friend_id)  what is the work of friend_id  as parameter

Comment: @alert You probably want to do `<button onclick="add_friend(<?php echo $row['id']?>" />` where `$row['id']` contains the friend ID to be added (Assuming this is an integer). This is passed to the add_friend function which passes that along to the ajax request.